# Xpath Index wont work

Tags: xpath

I need the third image with that class and parent. None of these xpaths seem to be valid.

```
xpath=(//div[@class='itemTileV5'])//img[@class='dealItem']/@src[3]
xpath=(//div[@class='itemTileV5']//img[@class='dealItem'])/@src[3]
xpath=(//div[@class='itemTileV5']//img[@class='dealItem']/@src)[3]
```

Notice I move the parentheses around and it's always an invalid path. Without parentheses it won't work either.
Please help.

```
<div class="itemTileV5">
 <div class="top">
  <a href="/Grocery_deals/p_pepperidge-farm-goldfish-variety-pack-bold-mix-29-4-ounce">
   <img class="Item" src="https://img.google.com/ai/184x184/dealimage/1493649114.jpg" alt="Pepperidge Farm">
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show your input xml and what elements you want to extract ?

Comment: @svasa done, but it doesn't really matter since the path is invalid. It's not saying it can't find the item.

Comment: What element do you need to extract ? is it just `src` ? why do you use `[3]`?

Comment: @svasa yes just the source. I use [3] because I need the third element that matches that criteria. There could be many images with that class that have a parent with the listed class as well.

Comment: Try `//div[@class='itemTileV5']/img[@class='dealItem']/@src` you don't need two backslashes before `img` and no `()` needed. Also I don't see `dealItem` in your xml, if that is case replace `dealItem` with `Item`

Comment: @svasa, where would the index go? I can retrieve them fine without listing the index [3].

Comment: Is this XPath 1,0, 2.0, 3.0, or 3.1?

Comment: What error message are you getting? (Don't tell us something fails, tell us HOW it fails).

Answer (score 0):

All three of your expressions are valid in all versions of XPath. If you're getting an error, please tell us what it is, and what XPath processor generated it.

The first two expressions aren't useful, because @src[3] selects the third attribute called "src" and there can only be one attribute with a given name.

Your informal requirement "the third image with that class and parent" seems to translate to `(//div[@class='itemTileV5']/img[@class='dealItem'])[3]/@src`